# how to change sanbox.paypal site to paypal site in django-merchant?

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I am using django-meerchant for paypal payment http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-merchant/en/latest/offsite/paypal.html ...

and my views have this code :

```
                            pay_pal = get_integration("pay_pal")
                            pay_pal.add_fields({
                                   "business": client.paypal_id,
                                   "item_name": product.name,
                                   "invoice": inst.trans_code,
                                   "notify_url": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/book/'+str(inst.id) +'/success/?booksaved=1',
                                   "return_url": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/book/'+str(inst.id) +'/success/?booksaved=1',
                                   "cancel_return": settings.BASE_DNS + str(client.id) + '/?booksaved=0',
                                   "amount": inst.book_charged})
                            return render_to_response("pay_pay.html", {"obj": pay_pal, "product": product.name, "amount": inst.totalcost},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my template pay_pay.html

```
{% extends "main_base_bookingpage.html" %}
{% load billing_tags %}

{% block content %}
    Required Parameters from the view
    <ul>
        <li> item_name : {{ product }}</li>
        <li> amount : {{ amount }}</li>
    </ul>
    {% paypal obj %}
{% endblock %}
```

my question is how can i change it so that it will change to the paypal site and not to sandbox.paypal site?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs you could either specify [test_mode](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-merchant/en/latest/offsite_processing.html#attributes) parameter when calling `get_integration` (`pay_pal = get_integration("pay_pal", test_mode=False)`), or set [MERCHANT_TEST_MODE](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-merchant/en/latest/gateways/paypal_gateway.html?highlight=MERCHANT_TEST_MODE#usage) in settings file. Also you may need to change `PAYPAL_TEST` setting too.

PS. I don't work with django-merchant and don't know whether this will work, this is just assumptions from the docs.

Comment: thanks demalexx, i try your answer `test_mode=False` and it works. in my code, before the `return render_to_response(...)`, i added : `pay_pal.test_mode = False` ...